# Brick Breaking Game: How Do I Break The Bricks?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to do a bricks breaker game using java, I did the pounding between the ball and the bricks but I don't understand how to make bricks disappear when the ball touches them. I think I should use boolean.
I'm still a beginner, so I don't use class, etc...

I tried to do a void to check if the brick had been touch or not but still don't working, my issue is in the void draw_Brick() function.

```java
int movementX, movementY;
int x, y;
int w, z;
int b, v;
int n, m;
int g, h;

void setup() 
{
  size(600, 600);
  background(0);
  x = 200;
  y = 300; 
  movementX = -3;
  movementY = 6; 
  w = 280;
  z = 400;
}
void draw() 
{
  Clear();
  movement();
  pounding();
  dessiner();
  draw_Brick();
}
void Clear() 
{  
  background(0);
}
void dessiner() 
{
  smooth();
  fill(255);
  rect(w, z, 85, 25);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  fill(255);
  text("movementX: "+movementX, 480, 570);
  text("movementY: "+movementY, 480, 583);
}
void movement() 
{
  x = x + movementX;
  y = y + movementY;

  w = (mouseX);
}
void draw_Brick()
{
  for (int n = 0; n < 3; n = n + 1) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 3; m = m + 1) {
      int b=m*250;
      int v=n*70;
      int g=85;
      int h=25;
      fill(255, 0, 0);
      rect(b, v, g, h);
      println("y: "+y);
      println("m: "+m);

      if (y<v+25 && y>v && x<b+85 && x>b) {
        movementY = -movementY;
        //g=0;
        //h=0;
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        rect(b, v, g, h);
      }
    }
  }
}
void pounding() 
{
  // si on est trop à droite et que le déplacement horizontal est positif
  if (x > width-10 && movementX > 0) 
  {
    movementX = -movementX; // inverser la valeur
  }
  // si on est trop bas et le déplacement vertical est positif
  if (y > width-10 && movementY > 0) 
  { 
    movementY = -movementY; // rendre négative la valeur
  }
  // si on est trop haut et le déplacement vertical est negatif
  if (y < 10 && movementY < 10) 
  {
    movementY = abs(movementY); // rendre positive cette valeur
  }
  //pounding sur la console
  //if (y>z-15 && x<w+85 && x>w)
  //{
  //movementY = -movementY; // inverser la valeur
  //}
  if (y<z+25 && y>z && x<w+85 && x>w) {
    movementY = -movementY; // inverser la valeur
  }
  if (x < 10 && movementX < 10)
  {
    movementX = -movementX;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would essentially have to "undraw" the brick with the way that this is set up. It would work best to create brick objects, so that when you know that they are contacted, you could simply delete them.

Comment: Hmmm OK, but how to check if the ball hit my object (like bricks or paddle)

Comment: You would have to check and see if the location of the ball is the same as part of the brick. That's why this approach is going to make that a pain.

 You would have to check the location of the ball(at any given time) to see if it contacted. So basically is x or y of the ball is the same as any of the x's and y's of the bricks.

Answer (score 1):

So, the way you have it set up, it's going to be extremely difficult. Your best bet is to make a Brick class. The challenge you're going to face is less to do with the brick disappearing from the screen and more to do with where the ball will bounce once the brick is gone. How it's set up right now, it looks like you're just reversing the ball when it reaches certain areas on the screen, which means it's not actually interacting with the bricks, so if you make the brick disappear (could just draw a rectangle over top of it), the ball will still bounce off the spot that it used to be. You could do something with setting a boolean for each area of the screen that would have a brick, but then the conditionals in your pounding() method will start to get out of hand, especially as your game gets bigger (multiple rows of bricks, for example). By having these things as objects (the bricks, ball, and paddle), you can manage direct interactions between them, so instead of just checking if the ball is in a certain spot where a brick would be, you can check to see if the ball has actually hit a brick, and then remove the brick.

Comment: But once I created a brick class how can I check if the ball hit the bricks?